# Highchart stack labels don't show up in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, highcharts

I have chosen Highcharts for its compatiblity with older versions of IE since it is going to be used in an old ASP based intranet that only runs in IE8.

Everything seems to work fine, except that stack labels are not shown in IE8. For this application, that's really a major disappointment.

See this [official example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked).

The stack labels above the columns are not rendered in IE8.

Is this a known problem, and is there a fix for it?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Issue reported - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have debugged `highcharts.src.js` and found a fix:

In line 15520, change the last `true` to `false` :

```
label[this.options.crop === false || chart.isInsidePlot(alignAttr.x, alignAttr.y) ? 'show' : 'hide'](true);
```

vs

```
label[this.options.crop === false || chart.isInsidePlot(alignAttr.x, alignAttr.y) ? 'show' : 'hide'](false);
```

Then it works in IE8. And it still works in new browsers BTW.

Don't know if this is the correct/best fix, but it does the job.

Comment: I will await a possible better answer (perhaps from Highcharts) before I accept my own.